# Get an object property name as string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Is it possible to get the property names of an object as an array of strings?

For example if I made the object:

```
var obj = {
 prop1: true,
 prop2: false,
 prop3: false
}
```

s there a some method 'getPropNames(obj)' that would return an array where each element is a property name so it would look like this:

```
props[0] = "prop1" 
props[1] = "prop2" 
props[2] = "prop3"
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for `Object.keys(obj)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too.

```
function  getPropName(obj) {
    var propNameArray= [];
    for (var propertyName in obj) {
      propNameArray.push(propertyName);
      }
    console.log(propNameArray);
  }
```

Comment: the dredges up inherited properties, not just own properties. it's unclear from OP if that's good or bad for his needs...

Comment: @dandavis Yes, agreed. If required, we can use `hasOwnProperty` check.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library on GoogleScriptExamples.com
[underscoreGS](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/underscoregs#TOC-_keys-Object-obj-)

```
function checkKeys(){
    var obj = {
     prop1: true,
     prop2: false,
     prop3: false
    };

    var keys = underscoreGS._keys(obj);
    Logger.log(keys);
}
```

Library project key: MiC3qjLYVUjCCUQpMqPPTWUF7jOZt2NQ8